# Are you allowed to drink coffee/water during any part of the prayers?

Tags: tefilla, food

Is there any part in the tefillah (pesukey dizimra, birchos shema, ashrey/uva letzion, etc) where one is allowed to drink coffee/water?

Comment: Please synch the content of the question with the title. Coffee / tea may be different than water,. I assume that you mean a congregant. As a Torah reader and occasional chazzan, I drink a sip of water to soothe my horse throat. Otherwise, I have trouble singing / reading the Toraah, and that affects the service, itself. Offhand, I don't think this is a problem. I'm not drinking for the pleasure of drinking. I'm doing it so that I can continue the prayer service for the rest of the congregation's benefit.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/may-i-drink-water-while-wearing-tefillin

Comment: DanF, nice catch I meant coffee/water.

Comment: Once you have recited the blessing for Torah study you can have water or coffee or tea. So then, or right after the morning blessings and before you start pesukei d'zimra, would be a good time to imbibe. Not sure about the other times.

Comment: @kordevero, you may not drink coffee prior to reciting birchos hashachar? What's your source?

Comment: @Ani pretty sure the Mishna Berurah says something along those lines.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26343/may-the-prayer-leader-drink-water-to-lubricate-his-voice-during-the-weekday-pr

Answer (score 1):

That question was answered over at [din.org](http://dinonline.org/2011/09/18/drinking-during-davening/) - water is indeed permissible in most circumstances - coffee (without sugar and milk) typically has the same law as water

> After davening Shacharis [on Shabbat], one must make Kiddush before drinking water.
>
> However, this applies only to drinking water for the purpose of
>   quenching one’s thirst. If a person is not thirsty, and wishes to
>   drink water for the purpose of clearing his throat, there is no
>   obligation of kiddush even after Shacharis [see also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26345/11501) on MY]
>
> Before *Shacharis*, there is no obligation of *kiddush*, and it is
>   permitted to drink water before davening. During *pesukei de-zimra*, the
>   problem is the obligation of reciting the shehakol blessing, and
>   similar principles to the above will apply.
>
> If the purpose of drinking is only to clear the throat, no berachah
>   (shehakol) needs to be made, and where required one can drink a little
>   during *pesukei de-zimra*, without concern for a *hefsek* (interruption).
>   *Poskim* discuss whether an ‘action’ (*ma’aseh*) constitutes a *hefsek*, and
>   the general concensus is that it does not (see Shut Mekor Chayim,
>   Orach Chaim 2, concerning the act of writing).
>
> If, however, one feels thirsty, a *shehakol* needs to be made, and one
>   should avoid this during *pesukei de-zimra*.